# how to calculate shannon entropy of byte bigrams

Tags: matlab, statistics

I have read a image file into a array like this

```
A = imread(fileName);
```

and now i want to calculate shannon entropy. The shannon entropy implementation found in maltab is a byte level entropy analysis which considers a file to be composed of 256 byte levels.

```
wentropy(x,'shannon')
```

But i need to perform a bigram entropy analysis which would need to view a file as consisting of 65536 levels. Could anyone suggest me a good method of accomplishing this.

Comment: I am interested. Can you define the math a little better?

Answer (score 5):

The entropy of a random variable can be calculated using the following formula:
[image]

Where `p(x)` is the `Prob(X=x)`.

Given a set of `n` observations `(x1, x2, .... xn)` You then compute `P(X=x)` for the range all x values (in your case it would be between `(0 and 65535)` and then sum across all values. The easiest way to do this is using `hist`

```
byteLevel = 65536
% count the observations

observationHist = hist(observations, byteLevel);
% convert to a probability
probXVal = observationHist ./ sum(observationHist);  

% compute the entropy
entropy = - sum( probXVal .* log2(probXVal) );
```

There are several implementations of this on the file exchange that are worth checking out.

**Note**: where are you getting that `wentropy` is using 256 byte levels?  I don't see that anywhere in the docks?  Remember that in Matlab the pixels of a color image have 3 channels (R,G,B) with each channel requiring 8 bits (or 256 byte levels?).

Also because each channel is bound between `[0 256)` you could create a mapping from `P(R=r,G=g,B=b)` to `P(X=x)` as follows:

```
data = imageData(:,:,1);
data = data + (imgData(:,:,2) * 256);
data = data + (imgData(:,:,3) * 256 * 256);
```

I believe you can then use `data` to calculate the total entropy of the image where each channel is independent.

Comment: Nice! thus you are calculating sort of redundancy of the image from the chromatic point of view, right? The point is why 65536? @Crowso, are you working with one "joint" color channel 16bit wide?

Comment: @Acorbe, yes entropy is a measure of the uncertainty or information contained in a random variable. If a random variable produces results with a high level of uncertainty it has a lot of entropy. Likewise if the uncertainty is low so is the entropy.

Comment: Now you have 16M bit, though. May the user have a 6bit/color image?

Comment: @Acorbe yes, that is correct that X can take on values between `[0, 2^24)`. Its not entirely clear what the OP actually wants to do

Answer (score 0):

Convert color image with "65536" levels to gray image with "256" levels and consider entropy evaluation.