# Shannon's Entropy calculation

Tags: matlab, statistics, probability, information-theory

I have a probability distribution that defines the probability of occurrence of `n` possible states.

I would like to calculate the value of Shannon's entropy, in bits, of the given probability distribution.

Can I use `wentropy(x,'shannon')` to get the value and if so where can I define the number of possible states a system has?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to calculate shannon entropy of byte bigrams](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13344760/how-to-calculate-shannon-entropy-of-byte-bigrams)

Comment: entropy in *bytes*? are you sure?

Comment: @A.Donda I just edited it to 'bits.' (great example of why they should not have minimum character number on edits, as I had to make other edits just to fix it: single words can be important).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you already have the probability distribution, call it `p`, you can do the following [formula for Shannon Entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_%28information_theory%29#Definition) instead of using `wentropy`:

```
H = sum(-(p(p>0).*(log2(p(p>0)))));
```

This gives the entropy `H` *in bits*.

`p` must sum to 1.

Comment: Thank you. One more question, how to define the probability distribution in matlab? As a vector? [0,0.5,0.8...]

Comment: Yes, values <1, _summing to 1_. You seem to be showing the start of a cdf, not a pdf.

Comment: The main concern that I have is the approach. I have a vector of probabilities of each state of the system. For example if a state has a probabilistic value of 1 it's likely to be the current state, and if it's value is 0 it's an impossible state of the system. Thank you again.

Comment: Yes, that's the idea of a probability distribution, but remember that the probability of all states must sum to one.

Comment: You are right, but I'm hesitant to call it a pdf because the probabilities act like a constraints on the possible states of a system therefore decreasing its entropy level. For example if I have three of the states that are equally likely and one that's impossible I would write it down as [1,1,1,0]. I hope that my approach isn't too unorthodox.

Comment: I follow, but you _must_ divide by the sum to get `p`. The nonzero states in `[1 1 1 0]/3` are all equally likely.

Comment: I could write [0.33,0.33,0.33,0], but i have to be able to use additive constraints, for example i would like to impose another constraint to further limit the possibilities.

Comment: Then normalize `p` each time you introduce a constraint.

Comment: Lets say I have constraints imposed by one probability distribution [0.33,0.33,0.33,0], lets call this a constraint1. But when i have another constraint that I would like to impose to further limit the states(change their probability distributions), for example [0,0.5,0.5,0], how should I consolidate those two to get a final probability distribution of the system.

Comment: I really appreciate your help.

Comment: If I understand correctly: Say you have `p=[0.33 0.33 0.33 0]` and `c=[0 0.5 0.5 0];`, then element-wise multiply and normalize: `p_c = p.*c; p_c = p_c/sum(p_c);`. Not the best example since the result is `p_c = [0 0.5 0.5 0];` but I _guess_ that is what you want.

Comment: @user2703038, what kinds of constraints do you need?

Comment: @chappjc Thank you, that makes perfect sense. And the results are logical.